# Open Sans looking weird on every browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, google-fonts

3 days ago out of nowhere, I noticed that some sites I've built before using "Open sans" font from Google fonts as the main font are looking strange, choppy and pixelated on Chrome.

I've tried several fixes, going from adjusting the ClearType on Windows to disabling flags (accelerated 2d canvas) and disabling hardware acceleration on Chrome, pretty much tried everything I could find on the internet, and nothing works.

I also tried removing "Open sans" from my Windows font folder, but the font still looks pixelated on my sites. It was fine in Photoshop before I removed it.

This is a screenshot of what I am currently seeing.

[open sans strange behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzIKu.png)

The `p` tag is using a simple CSS for testing

```
font-family: 'Open sans';
font-size: 12px; / 20px (on the bellow paragraph)
font-weight: 700; / 400 (on the bellow paragraph)
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

On the style, I have the default @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap'); from Gooogle fonts.

Can anyone shed a light? Any help is appreciated. I don't really want to format my computer just because of this damn buggy font. Also tested on Edge and Opera GX, and it happens on them as well.

Comment: I can confirm I'm seeing this too. Some sizes are worse than others - at 20px curved uppercase letters such as D, C and G are a complete mess. I can't release a website to the client looking this bad.

Comment: yeah the numbers are rendered weird too, i have no idea of what to do

Comment: If it helps, we ended up going with Roboto for now, it was similar enough for our purposes.

Comment: i wish i could change, but we have almost 700 sites using open sans as standard, the choice of switching fonts is not viable, but since it's my computers problem (my co-workers doesnt have this rendering problems) i will just forget about it...it's freaking annoying but, there is nothing i can do, tried everything

Comment: This is definitely happening. I'm surprised there's not more about it elsewhere on the web, but this is the only mention I could find (so at least I know it's not just us). It seems unlikely that Google doesn't know about this, but maybe they actually don't. Is there some way to let them know? I can't imagine that this is intentional or something that should require a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure if it's open sans. You can check it with [whatfont plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm.)

Comment: installed the plugin, and yes it recognizes the font as Open Sans, good plugin btw

Comment: can you give me a link or demo? Maybe I will find a bug.

also you can try add 1-2 px. I had similar bug with font-size: 13px, but with font-size: 14px everything was fine.

Comment: this is the test ive linked as image on the post

http://vivarte.com.br/teste.html

the thing about the font-size, i have like almost 700 model sites of plataforms that we use for clients to do online auctions, and the menu text size is 12px, i can't really affort to change it...

but i guess it's only on my computer that i'm having issues, everyone else is saying that the sites are normal, i kinda wanted to fix my issue, but i've done so much and nothing works, im giving up

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into the same issue using Google Fonts' Open Sans, both via the `@import` method and the `<link>` method. Tested this against Brave (Version 1.30.89 Chromium: 94.0.4606.81), Chrome (94.0.4606.71), and Firefox (93.0). It exhibits this graininess on the fonts.google.com demo site at sizes like 18-20px, but at 16px or 21px the issue isn't present.

Interestingly, Adobe Fonts' version of Open Sans doesn't exhibit this issue, and is clear and antialiased at all sizes. I swapped my Google implementation with Adobe's `<link>` implementation instead and encountered the same issue.

However, inspecting Adobe's demo revealed they've also added a CSS property: `font-feature-settings: 'calt', 'clig', 'kern', 'liga', 'locl', 'rlig';`. These are OpenType features, and adding this to my styles seems to resolve the issue, but only for the Adobe implementation; it did not resolve the issue with Google's version. Perhaps Google's version of Open Sans lacks these additional features.

Comment: omg, thank you, even tho open sans from google still grained for me, using the link from adobe is totally fine, i will just switch to adobe till google fonts are ok for me to use again. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, viz. Open Sans were looking jittery on our website (exactly as shown in the screenshot)

The problem was (kind of) solved when I used Adobe's Open-Sans version, as suggested in the comments.

Finally, I discovered that in our CSS we were using a font-weight (300) that we weren't importing from google fonts.

When added, everything worked smoothly, so we're back to Google Fonts.